# Pair values from two lists

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists with me as per the following example.

```
List<string> words = new List<string>() {"V","H","M" };

List<int> numbers = new List<int>() {10,20,30 };
```

I need to pair the values of these two lists so that my output needs to be exactly like the following text.

Desired output :  `V10 H20 M30`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Zip` method for that.

You can try the following:

```
String.Join(" ", words.Zip(numbers, (first, second) => first + second))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = words
  .Zip(numbers, (w, n) => $"{w}{n}");

Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but here's a very simple way of doing it without Zip: (x = item, y = index)

```
var mergedList = words.Select((x, y) => $"{x}{numbers.ElementAt(y)}");
```